# The determinant of f is not invertible when f is zero when the norm of the function is constant.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential

Let $f:U\subset \mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ differentiable on the open $U$. If $|f(x)|$ is constant, then $Df(a)$ is not invertible for every $a\in U$.

How can I prove that?

Comment: Do you remember the inverse function theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|f(x)\| = 0$, then clearly $Df(x)$ is zero for all $x$.

Suppose $\|f(x)\| \neq 0$. Let $\phi(x) = {1 \over 2} \|f(x)\|^2$. Since $\phi$ is constant, we have
$D \phi(x) = f(x)^T {\partial f(x) \over \partial x} = 0$. If ${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} $ was invertible this would imply that $\|f(x)\|= 0$, a contradiction. Hence ${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} $ is singular everywhere.

Comment: I think it's right, Thanks you! but I have a doubt. How do you compute $D\phi(x)$? I suppose that you used the chain rule but I can't compute the derivative of the norm.

Comment: this is the derivation of a quadratic form.

Comment: It is the derivative of the square of the norm.